# Battery charging in Ubuntu ridiculously slow

Tags: 16.04, power-management, lenovo, battery, ideapad

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 310-15IKB, which I dual booted with windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The laptop is just a couple of month old.

When I run windows charging from 5% to 100% takes ~ 2 hours. And the indicator which shows time to charge remains precise.

In Ubuntu though, the charging is very fast for almost 20 mins (indicator shows less than 2 hrs), but after that, the charging rate(and time to full) keeps going up and down and the laptop takes a ridiculously large time to charge.

[image: Time to full]

[image: Charge Rate]

The above two images show the time to full and corresponding charging rate during laptop charge (17% to 55%).
I have tried finding the solution but I couldn't find anything. Could anybody please help?!

Comment: If you are willing to help troubleshoot the problem, then please file a bug report.

Comment: @user535733 I am fairly new to  Ubuntu and have never filed a bug report before.  All the bug filing procedure on the internet seems fairly cryptic. Could you please guide me to a link which states clearly what to do.

Comment: It's difficult to file a useful bug report with enough information to isolate the problem. You might be talking about a hardware-related problem, and none of the developers will have exactly your hardware - their battery charging numbers are just fine. If you wish to experience the journey, start at  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Sometimes my battery not charging or charging slowly.
To solve the problem,
I changed `ADVANTAGE CHARGE BATTERY CONFIGURATION` on `Enabled` (Bios).